# Tomar los valores desde un desplegable hacia un campo de texto

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Buenas tengo realizado mi código. El cual esta tengo un desplegable y un campo de texto. La función es cuando el usuario seleccione un desplegable este valor seleccionado se escriba automáticamente en un campo de texto.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Rutinaria" runat="server" style="font-size:25px; width:180px;">
                              <asp:ListItem Selected="True"  value=" "></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Formación"> Formación </asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Mant. Preventivo"> Mantenimiento Preventivo</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Intervención Externa"> Intervención externa </asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Parada Túnel"> Parada Túnel </asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>


  <asp:Label   ID="labelMotivo" Text="Motivo" style="font-size:20px;" class="Info_Label" runat="server" />
                      <asp:TextBox ID="txtMotivo" style="font-size:20px; width:180px;"   runat="server"/><br></br>
```

Tengo el desplegable y el campo de texto ahora muestro el codigo. Declaro una variable y su función. Esta es la forma que implementado yo pero si tienen alguna idea diferente para realizar la función lo agradecería ya que con lo que he realizado no funciona seguramente este mal echa la variable. ¿Como puedo formarla correctamente?

```
var valor1 = (?$("[id$=Rutinaria]").val());
 $("[id$=Rutinaria]").change(function() 
{
 if ($("[id$=Rutinaria]").val() != 0)
  { 
    $("[id$=txtMotivo]").val(valor1);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal mente si es obligatorio, se deja la primera opcion como desactivada, para que una vez tomada una opcion no se puede dejar de selccionar

```html
<asp:DropDownList ID="Rutinaria" runat="server" style="font-size:25px; width:180px;">
                          <asp:ListItem disabled selected value=""></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Formación"> Formación </asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Mant. Preventivo"> Mantenimiento Preventivo</asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Intervención Externa"> Intervención externa </asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem value="Parada Túnel"> Parada Túnel </asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>
```

Y ahora actualizo el input tomando el valor del select despues de cambiar.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Rutinaria").change(function() {
    if ($("#Rutinaria").val() != '') {
      $("#txtMotivo").val($("#Rutinaria").val());
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Gracias eso me ha servido